# Regex to capture date and hours along with a int on a string

Tags: regex

Having this string:

```
File: `myfile.txt'
  Size: 310624485   Blocks: 606704     IO Block: 131072 regular file
Device: 13h/19d Inode: 14942600    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-11-21 06:00:31.293377534 +0100
Modify: 2017-11-21 06:01:33.203998797 +0100
Change: 2017-11-21 08:53:41.563936838 +0100
 Birth: -
```

I want to get two capturing groups:

- The number besides `Size`, in the example above `310624485`
- The date and hour besides `Modify` until the dot, in the example above `2017-11-21 06:01:33`

I got the first group by using the following regex:
`Size: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)`

But I'm not able to get the `Modifty` one.

Can someone give me a hand and tell me how can I get both capturing groups, here's the Regex: https://regex101.com/r/wdoqDn/1

Comment: Why not simply `Modify: (.*$)`?

Comment: Why do you need a regex, read the file line-by-line and look for the lines that start with "Size" and "Modify" respectively. Then process them.

Comment: Better yet, use a machine-readable interface to get the values in machine-readable form.  This looks vaguely like something you could get out of the `/proc` filesystem on Linux, but without more information about what you are trying to achieve, it's hard to say exactly where to look.  Or simply use the `stat` command to get information about a file.

Comment: `Size: ([0-9]+)` should be enough to capture the size, why are you using a more complex regex?

Comment: I can't change anything or do it in any other way. Due to our implementation and for other reasons I have to get those variables via regex. Just imagine that's an string and I want to get those variables, don't worry if there's other ways to do it better. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it combining the @TG's answer plus the info from the comments.
The thing that I missed was the `|` separator.

```
Size: ([0-9]+)|Modify: ([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})
```

Answer (score 1):

to solve Modify you can use 
`(Modify: )([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})`

and as someone mentioned in comment to catch size use simpler regex, for example `(Size: )(\d+)`

Java version:

`(Modify: )([0-9]{4}\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}\\:[0-9]{2}\\:[0-9]{2})`

`(Size: )(\\d+)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tg, but can you put the complete Regex? If I put the one of `Size` I made with yours, is not working. Thank you.

Comment: ok, but where you are using it? java? javascript? you probably have to make escape marks

Comment: I'm using PHP, but it's a Regex expression, so that doesnt matter, right?

Comment: You are using two different regular expresions. I need one single regular expresion (one line) thats capture two different groups, the `Modify` and the `Size`

Comment: well i don't think this is possible in regex :(